# retrieve available storages via JavaApi

Tags: orientdb

is it possible to retrieve available storage(s) when working with plocal:[dbPath] connection?

`db = new ODatabaseDocumentTx("plocal:[path]");

db.?`

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean all the storage type supported like plocal, remote, local and memory?

Comment: Hi lvca, i mean database names!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Collection<OStorage> storages = Orient.instance().getStorages();
```

It retrieves all the opened storages. To get the name call .getName() against the storage instance.

Comment: thank you, but in the pLocal mode I can retrieve only the current session, for instance: plocal:c:\db\mydb
other possible databases are not included, I should switch to remote type to getStorages!!

Comment: With plocal you can open any database on your filesystem, so there is no a pre-configured list of database. With a server, instead, all the databases are under databases directory.